# How to send notification to user on windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, notifications

I want to make breaks during PC work.

***How to sent notification to user every 50 min on windows 8.1?***

Comment: Use the task scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
//Sending a toast notification
public static async void SendNotificationAsync()
{
        NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("<connection string. with full access>", "<hub name>");
        var toast = @"<toast><visual><binding template=""Stop using your PC!""><text id=""1"">50 Minutes are over. Have a break.</text></binding></visual></toast>";
        await hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync(toast);
}
```

And:

```
//goes somewhere into your initialization part; initializes the timer and sets some variables
private Timer timer;
private int time;

timer = new Timer(){Interval = 1000*60};
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
```

-

```
//Timer class which is executed every minute?!
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if time (your countdown) is not null it's reduced by one again and again till it's null
    if(time--<=0)
    {
          //if the left time is finally null the timer is stopped and the toast notification fired off
          timer.Stop();
          SendNotificationAsync();
        }
        else
        {
          //actually nothing
        }
}
```

Comment: how does use this script? can you explain?

Comment: I'd add some comments.

Comment: can you add your comments?

Comment: They're already added. ^^

Comment: how to use this script? can you explain more about this script usage?

Comment: Well, the first part is the actual toast notification that is "executed" (kinda, not really executed but so it makes more sense maybe).  
The second part just sets and initializes the timer while the third part is the timer itself that reduces the value of a variable on every set tick till it's null (in this case it's null after 50mins.) and then it runs the sends the notification function.